# Why Firebase opening a browser everytime a user requests to get OTP for phone verification?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, facebook-unity-sdk

I am working on a game that requires user's phone verification to play the game. I am using Firebase Authentication. I have also added SHA keys to Firebase Project.I checked out some tutorials on youtube and found out that they are enabling `android device verification` API from Google Cloud but by 31 jan 2023 Google has DEPRECATED it and now we have to use `Play Integrity` API. Now i don't know if i am right or not but i guess i can't use this API if my game is not published on Google Play Store. Please Help As i am not publishing my game to Play Store.
This Is My Code

```
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Auth;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class FIrebaseAuth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_InputField phoneNumberInputField;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    private uint timeOut = 60 * 1000;
    private void Start()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Exception != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to initialize Firebase: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        });
    }

    public void VerifyPhoneNumber()
    {
        string phoneNumber = phoneNumberInputField.text;

        PhoneAuthProvider provider = PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(auth);
        provider.VerifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, timeOut, null, verificationCompleted: (credential) =>
        {
            // Auto-sms-retrieval or instant verification is successful.
            // Use credential to sign in the user.
        }, verificationFailed: (error) =>
        {
            // The verification process has failed.
            // Display an error message to the user.
            Debug.Log("send failed");
        }, codeSent: (id, token) =>
        {
            // Verification code was successfully sent via SMS.
            // Show the code input field to the user.
            Debug.Log("Code Sent");
        }, codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) =>
        {
            // Called when auto-sms-retrieval timed out and provides a way to handle this scenario.
        });
    }
}
```

I enabled Play Integrity from Google Could to give it a try but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Play Integrity requires being distributed through Google Play.

That said, [authentication and phone verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/phone-auth) can be done [without being on Google Play](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services).

Try running the project with Play Integrity disabled or try to replicate the issue using the [Firebase Auth test app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/auth/testapp).